# Фотоколлаж для Windows и Windows Phone 8.1 Univrsal App

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-8, мобильные-приложения

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать фотоколлаж, так чтобы можно было менять размер сетки, менять фотографии местами и двигать их. В Toolbox не нашел ничего подобного. С Win8.1 и WP работаю первый раз, может мануал какой есть или пример.

Просто разместить несколько картинок ,соединенных между собой, на экране я могу. Но вот, нужно еще иметь возможность редактирования коллажа [Пример приложения](http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2015-08/21/fpzxmjphchtr.png), красным выделены элементы которые позволяют изменять размеры сетки. Вот я не знаю как реализовать функцию редактирования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого элемента, чтобы в нём был готовый фото-коллаж - нету. Я сейчас занимаюсь разработкой фото-коллажа. И сделал я его следующим образом:
Разделяю `Grid` на `Rows` и `Columns` и потом сажаю фотки по алгоритму в конкретную клетку. А чтобы их можно было еще и перемещать, нужны три события (`event`'a) `MouseUp`, `Down`, `Move`.